# I am facing a lots of errors in creating a new app using ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, mobile-application

C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic> ionic start myApps blank
√ Creating directory .\myApps - done!
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? No
√ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

- IONIC  DEVAPP  *

  Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app
- Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
- LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

  ️-->      <--

> npm i
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):

```
    > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-59_binding.node
    Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-59_binding.node":

    HTTP error 404 Not Found

    Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
           try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

           export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

    or configure npm proxy via

           npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
    > node lib/post_install.js


    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext=
    --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Shahbaz Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@9.3.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',        gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',        gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
    gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
    gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext="
    "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules'
    npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Shahbaz
    Alam\Desktop\ionic\myApps\node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules'
    npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'C:\\Users\\Shahbaz
    Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\scss-tokenizer\\node_modules\'',
    npm WARN   errno: -4048,
    npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
    npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
    npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\Shahbaz Alam\\Desktop\\ionic\\myApps\\node_modules\\scss-tokenizer\\node_modules' }        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shahbaz Alam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-07T10_06_36_908Z-debug.log
```

Comment: just check whether git is installed in your system as well as try to remove the whitespace in your project foldername